# Drupal: hook_search only for a content type

Tags: drupal, cck

I would like to build a custom search module in Drupal 6 for searching through CCK. I need the user to search between his nodes (`node.uid=x`) and of a certain type (`type='xyz'`). I think I have to implement `hook_search` but I don't know where to put my filters. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try creating a [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) with an exposed filter, it's the absolute easiest way to implementing your idea.

Answer (score 2):

You already accepted an answer (which is probably the best option for you), but there are a few other ways to accomplish this.

IIRC, the [Custom Search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) module will work for what you want.

You can copy the stock `hook_search` function to a custom module and modify the query.  You can do something like this:

```
// ...
case 'search':
    // Build matching conditions
    list($join1, $where1) = _db_rewrite_sql();
    $arguments1 = array();
    $conditions1 = 'n.status = 1';

    // NEW BIT START
    $allowed = array(
        'content_type_1',
        'content_type_2',
        'content_type_3',
    );

    $types = array();
    foreach ($allowed as $t) {
        $types[] = "n.type = '%s'";
        $arguments1[] = $t;
    }
    $conditions1 .= ' AND ('. implode(' OR ', $types) .')';
    $keys = search_query_insert($keys, 'type');
    // NEW BIT END
```

This replaces the bit that extracts the type from the actual query string.

You would have to add in the bit to restruct to a particular `n.uid`.  I have been using this method lately, rather that Custom Search, because it simpler from the user's perspective.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try use [CCK Facets](http://drupal.org/project/cck_facets). But Views - of course simple.